# Large xml to csv in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csv

I need to convert a large xml file which is about 2gb into csv. Hence, I will run into out of memory exception as the xmldocument() is unable to load the whole file into memory. I have tried using xml reader but I am unsure how do I go about doing it without having the dtd for the xml

I have my code in c#

Comment: Sounds like a job for SSIS.

Comment: Could you post an example of the xml?

Comment: If this is accumulated data, that will grow further in the future, a CSV won't help you for long. You might want to consider switching to a database.

Comment: How would you do it using the `XmlDocument`?

Comment: XML is intended for sequential reading, so there is no need to load the entire file into the memory, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTD Processing is disabled by default when you use XmlReader.
XmlReader associated with a basic StreamWriter is efficient for us, as we treat files that are ~200 mb large.

Answer (score 2):

why can't you do this http://danbarnett.net/how-to-convert-large-xml-files-to-csv-78.html
 or use vtd-xml http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/

should be fairly simple for you with vtd-xml

Comment: I cannot find any tutorials on it. How do I use the dll, do you have any example? Or any tutorials I could follow to understand it better

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft developers using the XmlReader class to parse xml simply have to add the following two lines to their code to prevent the XmlReader from accessing URIs referenced in a DTD declaration:

```
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
```

where settings is an instance of the XmlReaderSettings class. Assigning a false value toProhibitDtd will prevent the XmlReader from throwing an exception when a DTD reference is encountered, whereas setting it true will, which will cause the reader to abort further parsing. Setting the XmlResolver to null causes the reader to ignore the externally referenced DTD. This allows the reader to parse the entire xml document without accessing an externally referenced DTD.

quoted from:
http://xponentsoftware.com/articles/Http_overload.aspx

Also, the OP indicated that the dtd file is not available. In that case, setting ProhibitDtd to false is not sufficient as an exception will be thrown if the dtd file is not found. Setting the XmlResolver to null solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you run on 64bit and want a quick fix for the OutOfMemoryException: go to your project properties -> build tab -> Platform target: change "Any CPU" to "x64".

You'll be able to load your 2GB XML file in an Xdocument.